# Spring MVC REST not null constraint does not work on missing request param

Tags: rest, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Not null validation does not work for a case:

```
@RestController
public class BookController {

 @GetMapping("/api/books/search")
 public Page<Book> get(@RequestParam(name = "bookId") @Valid @NotNull Long bookId, Pageable pageable) {
     .... // #1
 }
}
```

If I call `GET http://localhost:8080/api/books/search?bookId=` 
bookId is null on row #1. It's strange behaviour, cause if I do not provide bookId it fails.
`@NotNull` validation is not triggered.

Comment: Inside controller `if(bookId == null){//Do whatever you want}`

Comment: @SudhirOjha If the value of such parameter must not be null, then it's better to rely on Bean Validation. Have a look at my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57818215/1426227).

Answer (score 4):

> `@NotNull` validation is not triggered.

When you want the validation to be triggered, the controller class must be annotated with [`@Validated`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/annotation/Validated.html):

```java
@Validated
@RestController
public class BookController {
   ...
}
```

Quoting the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#validation-beanvalidation):

> To be eligible for Spring-driven method validation, all target classes need to be annotated with Spring’s `@Validated` annotation.

---

The [`@RequestParam`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html) annotation has a [`required`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html#required--) element where the default value is `true`. It simply indicates that the parameter itself must be present in the URL (either `?id` or `?id=`), but it doesn't require a non-null value for that parameter.  If you need to validate the value of such parameter, then you should use Bean Validation annotations.

Consider, for instance, the following controller method:

```java
@GetMapping("/foo")
public ResponseEntity<Foo> get(@RequestParam("id") Long id) {
    ...
}
```

The following request will result in a response with the `400` status code because the `id` parameter is not present:

```
GET /foo HTTP/1.1
Host: example.org
```

On the other hand, the following request is considered to be valid because the `id` parameter is present (even though there's no value associated with it):

```
GET /foo?id HTTP/1.1
Host: example.org
```

To refuse `null` values, use the [`@NotNull`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/validation/constraints/NotNull.html) annotation (and ensure that controller class is annotated with [`@Validated`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/annotation/Validated.html)):

```java
@GetMapping("/foo")
public ResponseEntity<Foo> get(@RequestParam("id") @NotNull Long id) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: `@Validated` works, but it's strange why `@RequestParam` required true is not triggered

Comment: @idmitriev `required = true` indicates that the parameter itself must be present in the URL (`?id`), but it doesn't require a non-null value for that parameter.

Answer (score 0):

There are different concepts. Method parameters annotated with @RequestParam are by default required. You can set @RequestParam(required = false) to disable this.

Your parameter however is of type Long (object). You can not give it and then by default it will be null (since you did not set a default - like @RequestParam(defaultValue = )).

Best way is to either set a default value or to check for null in your method.

Comment: `required = true` indicates that the parameter itself is required (not the value). See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57818215/1426227) for details.